# Idiomatic way to drop Pandas DataFrame column in an idempotent fashion (without settings errors="ignore")

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a more Pythonic or Pandas-idiomatic way to drop a `DataFrame` column without just setting `errors="ignore"`?

Suppose I have the following `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df_initial: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "country": "DE",
        "price": 1,
        "quantity": 10
    }
])
```

If I am unsure about when exactly a function that drops a column might be called (I am thinking in the context of a Jupyter Notebook), is there a way to do this that ***isn't just ignoring errors*** (like below)?

```py
df_country_dropped = df_initial.drop("country", axis=1, errors="ignore")
```

Perhaps I'm being too pernickety, but I had hoped that there would be a more Pythonic way to deal with this than just ignoring a `KeyError`.

I realise it is possible to check for the existence of the column before dropping:

```py
def drop_country_if_exists(df):
    if "country" in df:
        return df.drop("country", axis=1)

df_country_dropped = drop_country_if_exists(df_initial)
```

But I was hoping there might be a more elegant way!

Comment: if you think of `errors="ignore"` as `missing="ignore"`, this seems quite elegant to me

Comment: You could always just keep the columns your DO want. `df2 = df1[[ 'price', 'quantity']]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid the overhead of creating an additional function, I'd say that list comprehensions are a Pythonic way of achieving what you need.

An approach like this would be idempotent, and elegant enough:

```py
df[[col for col in df.columns if col != 'country']]
```

The upside with this method is that it's easily extensible if you want to drop a list of columns, by changing the `!=` to a `not in` and passing your list of column names.